# Como colocar um script dentro de outro

Tags: javascript, html

Esse código é para substituir o conteúdo de uma div, e preciso adicionar esse script dentro do código porém não estou conseguindo.

```js
window.onload = function substituir() {
  document.getElementById("fgh").innerHTML = "<div class="dmg"><script type="text/javascript" src="//ylx-1.com/bnr.php?section=post&pub=524113&format=468x60&ga=g"/>\n<noscript><a href="https://yllix.com/publishers/524113" target="_blank"><img src="//ylx-aff.advertica-cdn.com/pub/468x60.png" style="border:none;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:baseline;" /></a></noscript></div>"
}
```

```html
<div id='fgh'></div>
```

Comment: "dentro do código"? O que quer dizer com isso? E você escapou devidamente as aspas? Da maneira que está na pergunta não funciona, pois as aspas não estão devidamente escapadas, quebrando o código e deixando a sintaxe inválida.

Comment: É essa a duvida que eu tenho... se vc puder me explicar o que devo fazer ficaria muito grato!

Comment: Seu código está exatamente como mencionado? Pois se for, seu problema é com as aspas. Substitua as aspas duplas que envolvem a string a ser inserida, por aspas simples. `innerHTML = ' <div class="dmg">... '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem 2 problemas básicos no código:

**1º.** Como mencionado, você está usando aspas duplas como delimitador da string e dentro dela própria, sem fazer os devidos escapes (`\"`) nas aspas de dentro. Isso causa a quebra da string, resultando em erro. Neste caso, em vez de fazer escapes, basta delimitar a string por aspas simples (`'`).

Ao criar uma string onde haverá aspas dentro, ou você usa aspas duplas como delimitador e dentro aspas simples ou vice-versa, não as duas coisas ao mesmo tempo:

```
// aspas simples delimitando a string
// e aspas duplas internas
var string = '<div id="minhadiv"></div>';
```

ou

```
// aspas duplas delimitando a string 
// e aspas simples internas
var string = "<div id='minhadiv'></div>";
```

**2º.** Você está querendo inserir a tag `<noscript>` a partir de um `script`.

A tag `noscript` é justamente para detectar se o navegador não suporta scripts (ou está desativado nas configurações). Não faz sentido inserir essa tag a partir de um script, pois se você conseguir inserir, é porque o navegador executa scripts e a tag não fará nenhum efeito. Sem falar que você ainda está tentando inserir a tag dentro de um outro script, o que já é errado. A tag deve ser inserida diretamente no HTML e fora da tag `<script></script>`, algo como:

```
<noscript>
   Seu navegador não suporta scripts ou está desativado
</noscript>
<script>
   // códigos
</script>
```

> Pelo título da pergunta, o que estiver entre `<noscript></noscript>` não é script.

**[Sugiro ler esta documentação sobre a tag `<noscript>`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript)**